# Prevent numbers from being truncated with write.csv

Tags: r

I am trying to write.csv the output I created in R.

I have used the below function to remove scientific notations:

```
options(scipen = 999)
```

My output looks fine when I check in R. It looks like this:

| Party ID | Party Name |
| --- | --- |
| 38749473937474027876 | Hello |

and then I write my output to csv using the following function:

```
write.csv(parties, "...filelocation\\parties.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

The problem is, when I open my csv file, the output looks like this in csv:

| Party ID | Party Name |
| --- | --- |
| 38749473937474027000 | Hello |

this is not correct, so I tried the following ways:

```
write.csv(parties, "...filelocation\\parties.csv", row.names = FALSE, digits = 22)
```

and it still did not work. I also looked into the colClass function but I believe that is only for read.csv

If someone could please help me figure out how I can write.csv without having my long numbers rounded up, that would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the big integer in as `"character"` and then use a package meant to handle big integers, such as package [`gmp`](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=gmp), then you will have all the digits.

```r
x <- 'PartyID   PartyName
38749473937474027876    Hello'

library(gmp)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'gmp'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     %*%, apply, crossprod, matrix, tcrossprod

df1 <- read.table(textConnection(x),
                  header = TRUE,
                  colClasses = c("character", "character"))
as.bigz(df1$PartyID)
#> Big Integer ('bigz') :
#> [1] 38749473937474027876

df1$PartyID <- as.bigz(df1$PartyID)
df1
#>                PartyID PartyName
#> 1 38749473937474027876     Hello
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: thanks! this method works, but the problem is, when I convert to csv that's when the numbers are being truncated. I believe the problem is on the excel side and not on the R side

Comment: @On_demand Have you tried writing the df as character, without coercing that column to class `"bigz"`?

Comment: Thank you, this is what I tried: parties %>% 
  mutate(partyid=as.character(partyid)) %>% 
  write.csv( "...filelocation\\parties.csv", row.names = FALSE) - but I am still having the same issue. But when I read the same csv file back in r, the numbers were not rounded anymore. Have you come across something like this?